# Can SignInManager from asp.net core 2.2 target to run on 4.6.1

Tags: asp.net

Can SignInManager from asp.net core 2.2 target to run on .NET 4.6.1? I can't find definitive information.

Comment: Why not give it a try and see the results?

Comment: not sure how to